# Transfer entire database from postgresql to Greenplum server

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, greenplum

I know that greenplum and postgresql are very similar; what I haven't been able to determine is if I can execute a pg_dump and then import the entire database as is into the greenplum server, or will this need to be done by hand?

I've seen tangentially related answers which appear to indicate that it requires multiple steps, which is confusing to me since the any required transformations of the data should be deterministic and thus should be quite simple, correct?

Comment: I really doubt a dump from a modern PostgreSQL would restore on Greenplum; it doesn't understand a lot of PostgreSQL syntax and features, as it's a fork of an ancient PostgreSQL version (8.2 I think).

Comment: So there is actually no simple way to do this? No means of transferring directly from postgre to greenplum?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via ETL only, Not possible to copy data from any database to greenplum or vice versa